# Refresh button now not working

Tags: javascript, button

I made a simple refresh button that used to work, and when I say 'refresh' i mean refresh to the current page (clearing data) and not a 'backspace' button that goes to the previous page.

```
onClick="window.location.reload()"
history.go(0)
window.location.href=window.location.href
```

I usually use one of these to refresh my search function to clear the data for a new search, just by refreshing the page, but all of a sudden I am getting a previous page instead. I am not sure why. I was testing on chrome. The problem is the way it is now the previous page could be anything, including something offmy site like google search ect.

Has anyone any idea what i am doing wrong?

I also tried

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

and

```
window.location.reload(false)
```

but I seem to be going around in circles.

Comment: How is this related to `Java`?

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview of your post. Your formatting was incorrect, so I corrected it. Then you made it incorrect again, so I had to rollback by one revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<button onclick="window.location.reload(true);">Click me</button>
```

The "window.location.reload();" is javascript, to check if an error is occuring when you run this page press f12 to view your browser tools and move to the console then attempt to reload your page, any javascript error will appear there.

Comment: yeah sorry about the re editing, i am new to stackoverflow, my first time, be gentle

Comment: i tried that too, its just taking me back to the previous page instead of refreshing.

Comment: This may be due the structure of your site then, if both pages are accessed via the same URL. Can you provide more information of how this page and the previous page are related please?

Comment: I believe your original answer was correct. I had put the search/ refresh ect in to a js file and injected it into my site, however i didn't take notice and since i had several things i was working on i was editing the wrong blooming script. No wonder it wasn't working. 

Thankyou, your window.location.reload(true); answer worked. thanks so much

Comment: Please select an answer as being accept so the question can be closed :)